# Early function return with macro

Tags: r, metaprogramming

I'm looking for something like `stopifnot` but that jumps out one frame up instead of halting all execution.

```
# like stopifnot but forces results to be zero
# using fictional "magic_eval" to promote return to the calling function
return0ifnot <- defmacro(bool) if(!bool) magic_eval("return(0)")

f <- function(x) {
 return0ifnot(x>0)
 x<-x+1
} 

f(-1) == 0
f( 1) == 2
```

This could easily be done with `ifelse(x<0,0,x+1)` but I'm curious about metaprogramming within R and if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

`tryCatch` provides a mechanism to turn `stopifnot` into the desired function break, but does not get at a meta-programming solution.

```
tc_wrap <- function(f, default) function(...) tryCatch(f(...), error=function(e) default)
f_orig <- function(x) {
 stopifnot(x>0)
 x+1
}
f<-tc_wrap(f_orig, 0)

f(-1) == 0
f( 1) == 2
```